# project setup for Angular & webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

i am trying trying to create a project with webpack, angular and gulp. Webpack creates a bundle file called build.js and an index.html from a template. When the browser enters the webpage i want it to go directly to a login screen by using ui-route.

[this is how my directory structure looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bMK6.png)

Firstly my problem is that the bundle only includes the entry file, app.module.js. I can require the other js files in app.module.js to have them in the bundle to but when this project grows it will be a lot of files to be required in one file. So is it possible to bundle all js files except the once in node_modules folder?

My next problem is that when the build.js and index.html has been created in the dist/build folder i cant seem to find the rest of the html files in the project if they are not in the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your webpack config looks like, but many times the HTML is processed by webpack and might end up in your JS bundle (as a string) that then can be used by Angular.